# How to return unique elements in an array using Go's text/template package?

Tags: go

I am new to Go and I am struggling trying to figure out a way to return unique variables from an array in Go templating language. This is to configure some software and I do not have access to the source to change the actual program only the template.

I have knocked up an example in the Go playground:

https://play.golang.org/

```
package main

import "os"
import "text/template"

func main() {

      var arr [10]string
      arr[0]="mice"
      arr[1]="mice"
      arr[2]="mice"
      arr[3]="mice"
      arr[4]="mice"
      arr[5]="mice"
      arr[6]="mice"
      arr[7]="toad"
      arr[8]="toad"
      arr[9]="mice"

      tmpl, err := template.New("test").Parse("{{range $index, $thing := $}}The thing is: {{$thing}}\n{{end}}")
      if err != nil { panic(err) }
      err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, arr)
      if err != nil { panic(err) }

}
```

Right now this returns:

```
The thing is: mice
The thing is: mice
The thing is: mice
The thing is: mice
The thing is: mice
The thing is: mice
The thing is: mice
The thing is: toad
The thing is: toad
The thing is: mice
```

What I am trying to do is craft a template that from the input array filters duplicates and  only returns:

```
The thing is: mice
The thing is: toad
```

I am really stuck as I know virtually no go and struggle to find any array manipulation methods in the docs. Any one have any tips?

## Addenium

Sorry for not being clear I wrote this question on the bus on the way to work.

I don't have access to any go code outside the template. I have a template I can edit and within that template I have an array that may or may not have multiple values and I need to print them once.

I appreciate this is not how templates are meant to work but if there is some dirty way to do this it would save me several days work.

Comment: PS. I dont know which element in the array is the one I am after I only need to output unique array elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own functions for the template via `template.FuncMap`:

```
arr := []string{
    "mice",
    "mice",
    "mice",
    "mice",
    "mice",
    "mice",
    "mice",
    "toad",
    "toad",
    "mice",
}

customFunctions := template.FuncMap{"unique" : unique}

tmpl, err := template.New("test").Funcs(customFunctions).Parse("{{range $index, $thing := unique $}}The thing is: {{$thing}}\n{{end}}")
```

Where `unique` is defined as:

```
func unique(e []string) []string {
    r := []string{}

    for _, s := range e {
        if !contains(r[:], s) {
            r = append(r, s)
        }
    }
    return r
}

func contains(e []string, c string) bool {
    for _, s := range e {
        if s == c {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Output:

```
The thing is: mice
The thing is: toad
```

(It might be better to use a `map` .. but this gives you the basic idea)

That said - have you considered filtering this *outside* of the template? That would make things nicer for you.. then you can just iterate over the actual slice within the template.

Working sample: https://play.golang.org/p/L_8t10CpHW

Comment: Note that the `unique` function as written will only allow a string array of len 10.  It will not allow 9 or 11 which could cause problems when the sample data changes once @rickard has a working solution.

Comment: True. Fixed. Sorry about that! (Coffee is incoming!)

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I don't have access to code outside the template. The template gets loaded and is configuration to software. Is there no way to do this inside the template? It doesn't have to be pretty :)

Comment: Not that I am aware of no. I am not aware of any way to maintain state within a template - which you will require in order to know what is unique and what isn't.

Comment: I have just been attempting to maintain state within template, and without go function mapped its impossible.  You can assign to a variable, but if you do this within a `{{range}}` then its actually a new variable so therefore does not modify the original scope. @SimonWhitehead is correct.

Comment: In your working sample, why did you use `r[:]`? I believe `r` works as well? What's the difference?

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani this being a 6 year old answer I can't be 100% sure why I chose to use that syntax. Sometimes I try and account for other possibilities in my answers and this syntax would allow the OP to use a fixed size array as the input. Using `r[:]` then would create a slice from the array and continue working as expected. Other than that, I'm not entirely sure why I chose it.

Answer (score 0):

The template can acces a particular custom function http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#FuncMap. This allows your own logic to be called from within the template.

There is a comprehensive example in the docs which I wont repeat here.  The key line is setting up a funcion Map and providing this to the template:

```
 tmpl, err := template.New("titleTest").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(templateText)
```

Then can be accessed within the template.

```
 {{myCustomFuction .}}
```

Since now it is established that it will take more go code in the form of a mapped function to achieve, I thought I would share a thought that might get the job done.  If you have control of which template that the 'go' program you are not able to modify runs, then you could make several passes.  I am also assuming you are on linux.  Something like this:

```
goexe 'first template'    // this writes to 'text file'
cat textfile | sort | uniq > 'text file'
goexe 'second template'   // your desired output
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand how that would help guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: I mis-understood. What you need to look into is writing your own function which you can call from the template.  But essentially it has to conform to the correct `interface`.